# How to check whenever the latest select has changed (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, dom, select

I'm trying to detect whenever the latest input / select inside a .form-group has changed, for example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="title-label">Birthdate</label>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="pr-3">
            <select name="select-22" class="custom-select">
                <option selected disabled>Month</option>
                <option value="1">01</option>
                <option value="2">02</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="pr-3">
            <select name="select-4" class="custom-select">
                <option selected disabled>Day</option>
                <option value="Enero">Jan</option>
                <option value="Febrero">Feb</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <select name="select-3" class="custom-select">
                <option selected disabled>Year</option>
                <option value="1951">1951</option>
                <option value="1950">1950</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, change / blur to 'select-3' should trigger another action.

UPDATE:

I've solved this doing:

```
$('.form-group').on('change', 'select, input', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $elem = $this.closest('div').next().find('select, input');

    if($elem.length == 0) {
        console.log("Latest element changed");
    }
});
```

Comment: I did, but i couldn't make it work either with :last or last-child.

Comment: You need to *post* your attempt

Answer (score 1):

You can select all `.form-group` divs with getElementsByClassName, from there take the last element with select as its tag name and add an event listener on it

```js
let el = [...document.getElementsByClassName('form-group')[0].getElementsByTagName('select')].pop();
el.addEventListener('change', e => console.log(e.target.value));
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="title-label">Birthdate</label>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="pr-3">
            <select name="select-22" class="custom-select">
                <option selected disabled>Month</option>
                <option value="1">01</option>
                <option value="2">02</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="pr-3">
            <select name="select-4" class="custom-select">
                <option selected disabled>Day</option>
                <option value="Enero">Jan</option>
                <option value="Febrero">Feb</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <select name="select-3" class="custom-select">
                <option selected disabled>Year</option>
                <option value="1951">1951</option>
                <option value="1950">1950</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my final solution:

```
$('.form-group').on('change', 'select, input', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $elem = $this.closest('div').next().find('select, input');

    if($elem.length == 0) {
        console.log("Latest element changed");
    }
});
```